# How to read a string of integers received on python from serial arduino

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, list-comprehension, pyserial

I'm sending a list of values (e.g. 80,539,345,677) from Arduino to a Python app running on my RPi. I have not been successful in extracting the values and assigning them to respective variables or objects in the app.

Here's my code:

```
def read_values():
  #if DEBUG:
  print "reading arduino data"
  ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
  print "receiving arduino data"
  ser_line = ser.readline()
  print ser_line
  ser.close()
  ser_list = [int(x) for x in ser_line.split(',')]

  ambientLight = ser_list[1]

  print ambientLight

  return ambientLight
```

What I'm getting from Python is:

```
reading arduino data
receiving arduino data
80,477,82,2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serialXivelyTest4c.py", line 77, in <module>
run()

File "serialXivelyTest4c.py", line 63, in run
ambientLight = read_values()
  File "serialXivelyTest4c.py", line 27, in read_values
ser_list = [int(x) for x in ser_line.split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8254\r80'
```

You can see that I'm getting values, but that they're being truncated. Can anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong here. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used an Arduino but here's how I read from serial with a different board.  I used serial.

```
import streamUtils as su  # see below

ser = su.connectPort("/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART")  # make sure you have the right port name


data = ""
while True:
    try:
        data = data + ser.read(1)       # read one, blocking
        time.sleep(1)                   # give it time to put more in waiting
        n = ser.inWaiting()             # look if there is more
        if n:
            data = data + ser.read(n)   # get as much as possible
            # I needed to save the data until I had complete
            # output.  

            if data:
                # make sure you have the whole line and format
        else:
            break
    except serial.SerialException:
        sys.stderr.write("Waiting for %s to be available" % (ser.name))
        sys.exit(1)

sys.stderr.write("Closing port\n")
ser.close()
```

Here's the streamUtils.connectPort():

```
import serial

def connectPort(portname):
    # connect to serial port
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = portname
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
    ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
    ser.timeout = 15            # need some value for timeout so the read will end

    try:
        ser.open()
    except serial.SerialException:
        sys.stderr.write("Could not open serial port %s\n" % (ser.name))
        sys.exit(1)

    return (ser)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm using PySerial, so I don't think your example is going to work for me. Also, this seems to be more of an issue with parsing the values.

Comment: @RoboArch - are you sure readline is getting everything?  I had a similar issue, which is one of the reasons I went to reading it the way I did.  I had to make sure I had all the information before I formatted it.

Comment: No I'm not sure if I'm getting it all. I used your code nearly verbatim, but I can't get streamUtils to work. With serial it's freezing the app in the try: statement.

Comment: So sorry... streamUtils is something I wrote.  It uses serial.  The read() blocks and waits for another character, which appears to freeze.  I had to set a timeout value in order for the read to end.  I added the connectPort code to the answer above.

Comment: This timeout worked for me because I knew my input would end and I was looking for an ending value.  timeout value of 0 sets it to non-block, returning immediately after a read.

Comment: Will this work if I'm looping through the Arduino app and sending a new line every 10 seconds or so? I'm starting to think that I need to setup a call and response function for this to work at all.

Comment: Also, setting a timeout value won't work as the Arduino's response time can vary quite a bit.